# Get currency for country using `locale`

Tags: python, locale, currency

There is a way, using `locale`on python to get the currency of a specific country or having the currency code, knows which countries that official use this currency?

Comment: It sounds as if you're asking for an off-site package or data base.  If so, that's outside the Stack Overflow purpose.  Please clarify.

Comment: So, `locale` provides symbol, decimal characters, languages e so on. But not the correlation between ISO3166 and ISO4217 (US <-> USD or IT <-> EUR), correct? This is my doubt.

Comment: Please run `locale -a` and paste the output here.

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible for you to use my [`mpu`](https://github.com/MartinThoma/mpu) package:

```
import mpu
ger_currency = mpu.units.get_currency('GERMANY')
eur_currency = mpu.units.get_currency('EUR')
```

Now you have a mpu.units.Currency object:

```
>>> ger_currency.__dict__
{'code': 'EUR',
 'exponent': 2,
 'symbol': '\xe2\x82\xac',
 'withdrawal_date': None,
 'numeric_code': '978',
 'entities': ['GERMANY'],
 'subunits': '',
 'name': 'Euro'}
```

By now, the `entities` entry is just the current entity.

Answer (score 1):

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
db = locale.localeconv()
```

`db` is a `dict()` containing a bunch of keys, one of which (`int_curr_symbol`) is the currency symbol for the locale.

Dump it or see the `locale` documentation for more.

Comment: The `setlocale` doesn't recognize the second argument.

Comment: The second argument tells locale which locale description to open from the system. Which locales your system supports is not a python issue.

Comment: Yes, I now thats is not a Python issue. Just some new variable that I have to deal in a cross-platform software/script. So I will found a way.